# Website changes design when loaded with electron webview

Tags: browser, webview, electron

when I load [this](http://Hey,%20when%20I%20load%20this%20site%20via%20my%20own%20browser%20it%20looks%20quite%20nice%20and%20modern%20but%20when%20I%20load%20with%20the%20webview%20tag%20it%20in%20my%20electron%20application%20it's%20shown%20with%20an%20old%20theme.%20I%20already%20changed%20the%20browser%20agent%20and%20tried%20changing%20the%20size%20but%20that%20doesn't%20help,%20do%20you%20know%20how%20this%20webite%20can%20know%20that%20it's%20loaded%20from%20webiew%20and%20how%20I%20can%20bypass%20that?) site via my own browser it looks quite nice and modern but when I load with the webview tag it in my electron application it's shown with an old theme.
I already changed the browser agent and tried changing the size but that doesn't help, do you know how this webite can know that it's loaded from webiew and how I can bypass that?

New version:
https://ibb.co/RCbqH14

Old version:
https://ibb.co/1JHZzgc

```
  <webview id="todo" useragent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36" src="https://www.whatsmyua.info/" style="right: 0; height: 100%; width: 50%; position: fixed; z-index: 1; top: 0; overflow-x: hidden; padding-top: 20px;"></webview>
```

Comment: Why do you mean by old theme? It would help to post a screenshot of before/after.

Comment: i added it via links